# Max Listeners Exceeded Warning

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I have a discord music bot hosted on repl.it. Yesterday, it suddenly crashed while using it with 4 more people on a voice channel.

It stopped playing the music and on the bot console there was an "exit error 1"

This error was also on the console:

```
(node:33) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 disconnect listeners added to [VoiceConnection]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

The bot is using javascript to run.

How can I solve it?

Comment: It says "Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit" right in the error. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: I've read someone saying that adding this will just remove the warning, but not solve the problem. But i'll try and see if it worked, thanks!

Comment: How many listeners are supposed to be attached to VoiceConnection for your app to work?  If you only intended to attach one you probably are attaching it over and over and this is intended to prevent runaway processing.